# How to make distinct versions (development and production) of JS code?

Tags: javascript, nginx, docker

I develop small web application, distributed in Docker container, based on nginx image. It contains plain html and js code, without frameworks.

In JS code there is access to remote host via WebSockets. There is difference in environments: during testing on localhost, it works via http, on production server it uses https. So URL, which is passed to WebSocket, starts either with `ws://` or `wss://`

What is reliable solution to maintain two versions of these URL in code, considering I want to keep single Docker image for both development and production, and just use different Docker Compose configuration scripts?

There is example of work with WebSockets:

```
// This is for testing in localhost environment
var url = "ws://" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "bridge/";
// This is for working in production environment
var url = "wss://" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "bridge/";
BRIDGE.socket = new WebSocket(url);
```

Comment: please provide some code for the js or script that you are using

Comment: I don't think this is really related to Docker. You'd have the same issue even if Docker wasn't involved, correct?

Comment: @AndyShinn sure, without Docker, issue remains. But it related, because I want to solve it, using Docker capabilities. I already use different Compose configuration files overriding for other images in project.

Comment: I think in this case it is two different problems, it is first "how to have different base URLs in the same JavaScript project". After that is solved, it would either be apparent what to add (such as an environment variable) or a separate question for how to take the change to Docker Compose.

Comment: @AndyShinn you are right, problem can be easily split in two. In fact, second one is not a problem for me :) Maybe I was wrong, mentioning nginx and Docker, just wanted to give some context of problem. Maybe it would lead to solution more easily. Right now I am digging nginx ssi and variables, it seems it can be used as environment variables. I ll post solution if found any.

Comment: That was my point. But, I have an idea that you can try that can use environment variables which can easily be adapted for Docker Compose. I will post as an answer in case it is helpful.

Comment: @AndyShinn the main question now is how to make js mention about environment variables, passed from Docker. It is unclean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler "template substitution at runtime" idea that could work.

The base `nginx` image from Docker Hub actually has a utility from the  `gettext` package called `envsubst`. It can substitute environment variables inside files. We can leverage this at runtime by making a quick shell script as an entrypoint to do the substitution for us.

First, let's create the `entrypoint.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -n "$BASEURL" ]; then
  envsubst '$BASEURL' < /my.js.template > /my.js
  exec nginx -g "daemon off;"
else
  echo "you must specify \$BASEURL as en environment variable"
fi
```

This will look for a file at `/my.js.template`. My example file looks like:

```
var url = "$BASEURL" + window.location.pathname + "bridge/";
```

We'll need to wrap this up in a new Docker image based on the original `nginx`. The `Dockerfile` will look something like:

```
FROM nginx
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY my.js.template /my.js.template
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Now, assuming that `/my.js` was the file you wanted to replace the URL per environment, you can start this image like:

```
docker run -d -e BASEURL=wss://myhost mynewnginximage
```

It will replace the `$BASEURL` int eh template and write it out to `/my.js` and then execute `nginx` as PID 1 just as the original base image does.

Of course, you'd have to adapt the shell script paths to your actual code. But in theory, you can now use the same image, and just change the `BASEURL` environment variable per environment. In Docker Compose, you can specify a blank environment variable like:

```
environment:
  BASEURL:
```

This will instruct  `docker-compose` to use the `BASEURL` that is set on your local shell and pass it through to the container. So, you wouldn do `docker-compose up` like:

```
export BASEURL=ws://myhostfordev
docker-compose up
```

Let me know if something doesn't make sense and I can try to clarify. Alternatives to `envsubst` for more templating could be something like https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd instead which is a bit more powerful and can also take environment variables as input for templates.

Comment: I like your solution! envsubst at Entrypoint seems to be proper tool at proper place. In fact I think I ll go a bit further, passing such way not just a Websocket URL, but define JS-wide constant, like `APP_ENV = "$APP_ENV"`, and just use it in switch statements in code.

Comment: And, as you see, Docker was definitely related to problem solving ;)